# MVC3 deployment to IIS6 causes page not found but wildcard application maps have been set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I am deploying an MVC3 app to IIS6.  If I navigate to the starting point of the application myserver/myapp it redirects to myserver/myapp/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl= but it then show a 404 page not found error.

The views are in the correct folders.  Security permissions are correct.  If I deploy locally it works on my local iis7.5 perfectly.  wildcard application maps have been set (isapi stuff).  After creating a new default MVC3 app and deploying it to the iis6 website that works so there must be something different with the build?  The build specifies any cpu.  The application pool, the website and the virtual directory all specify .net4.  We can't update iis and we can't change servers.  Now, I'm out of ideas, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Uncheck "Verify that file exists" on the Add/Edit Application Extension Mapping dialog window for your wildcard mapping.

Comment: As simple as that!  Really, well it does now work!!!  Thanks ever so much :-)

Comment: Great, I'll move that to an answer for you. I left a comment as you didn't clarify if it was set or not in the question.  This is an issue I've ran into dozens of times as our company has moved to Asp.MVC with our IIS6 QA server environments, and I've spent plenty of sweat figuring it out. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck "Verify that file exists" on the Add/Edit Application Extension Mapping dialog window for your wildcard mapping.

Comment: Thanks :-) yup the reason I didn't add it into the question was because I didn't consider that!  Only took a half day of pulling my hair out!